# MySQL change data type for field

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have accidentally made a field on my database text when it is meant to be string. Do I need to delete the table and do it again or can I change it?

Comment: removed the python tag - this is not a Python question but a sql one.

Comment: Searching for "mysql change field type" yields a lot of useful answers. As a general rule, you are supposed to first research the topic by yourself before asking a question (and then mention what you found and why it doesn't solve your problem).

Answer (score -1):

You have to delete the field with ALTER TABLE "table_name" DROP "column_name"; and then add the new field with ALTER TABLE "table_name" ADD "field_name" "data type of the new field";

Comment: You don't need to drop the field - which would loose all existing data -, you can just modify it.